# Set browser cookie after google OAuth?

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, express-session

Im having problems authenticating users using google oauth. Especially setting the session cookie in the user's browser.

My front end:

```
function handleGoogleRegister() {
    window.location.href = `http://localhost:3002/auth/google`;
  }
```

Back end:

```
router.get('/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);

// Callback route after Google authentication
router.get('/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Successful authentication
    console.log("GOOGLE SUCCESS")
    console.log(req.user)
    req.session.user = {id: req.user.user_id, username: req.user.username}; // Set session cookie
    console.log(req.session.user)
    res.redirect(`${process.env.CORS_ORIGIN_URL}/register`);
```

No cookie is being set in the user's browser after this. But when i console.log `req.session.user` it logs the expected data. But for some reason, no cookie is being set in browser.. This sort of makes sense imo. As `/google/callback` is being requested by Google, and not my front end... Or? Very thankful for any input on this..

I expected the cookie to be set in browser, but this is not happening.

Comment: Hej Maria, I just posted a blog post about how to troubleshoot cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

The first step is to always use HTTPS. Using HTTP is a common source of cookie trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with a similar issue a few days ago and I spent a few hours to look for any insights or solution... At the end I found that **it was a browser (Chrome) issue/bug**.

I tried 2 other "clean" browsers (i.e. with no extensions installed), Opera on a Win PC and Safari on a MacBook, and the cookie was correctly set.

As a confirm, I set the cookie's `HttpOnly` flag to `false` and tried `document.cookie` in the Chrome console. The cookie was present and logged, even if it was not showing in the DevTools Application tab.